# open source freeware alternatives to FTP ZipDeploy?

Tags: ftp

The goal is to upload my whole website as a zip then unzip on the remote server.

Are there any freeware tools like FTP ZipDeploy that automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use rsync that is a great option.. you should consider using the backup directory option too so that you keep historical versions but keep them outside the public html area.

If you can't use rsync then you could use scp which will compress transfers for you.

If you can't use rsync nor scp then you can use something like CuteFTP (windows) which will compress transfers for you.

Comment: Note that rsync can compress on transfer so it's not slow, it's also excellent at only transferring what need to be transfered, so it's also not slow. As for the security comment... rsync can use SSH tunnels (or others) but does not have to, so it is security agnostic.

Comment: By default it uses an SSH tunnel.

Edit: As of release 2.6.0

Comment: Here's the links for the release notes if you're curious. http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-2.6.0-NEWS

Comment: Yep you're right.. the optional use of SSH tunnels is now the default.. it is still optional though :)

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to use rsync? It will conserve bandwidth/transmission time by not resending files that haven't been updated.

Comment: Yes, but it's encrypted. Assuming you care about security.